# Facing error "Unsupported Media Type" while not sending the content-type in APIs header using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Facing below error message while sending API requests without content-type header as few of APIs i am testing, do not require this content-type header.

```json
{
    "statusCode": 415,
    "code": "FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE",
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
}
```

I have configured the content-type in header as empty as well, but facing another issue.

```json
{
    "statusCode": 415,
    "code": "FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE",
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type: undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in JMeter, it worth [reporting it](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In the meantime if you don't want JMeter to add the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header you can change "Implementation" of your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to `Java`.

If you have > 1 HTTP Request sampler and want to change their implementation in a single shot - go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://guides.blazemeter.com/g/the-jmeter-pros-load-testing-checklist/23665)

[image]